# Securing a Whiteboard against the Wall

Tags: drywall, mounting

I've hung a reasonably sized whiteboard (72" wide by 60" tall) to the wall, but it only has two mounts at the top. One screw I've put in a stud and the other with a heavy duty drywall anchor. There are no holes, mounts or other hooks at the bottom.

My issue is that I'm nervous about kids leaning against it and pulling it down and/or the bottom is totally unsecured. Is there a bracket that I could to go into the wall at the bottom to both secure it to the wall and provide some additional support? I'm looking for something no wider than 2", that I could put into the wall below the board and kind of make an s-shape up over the bottom edge.

Any idea for something that might help here?

Rough idea how this might work - from the front:
[image: Whiteboard mount from the front]

From the side:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for putting such effort into your illustrations. Could you please also supply a photo of the whiteboard including one of the frame, which is likely aluminium, and the mounts. How wide is the frame? How thick is the whiteboard? I will then try to write my best complete answer.

Comment: What sort of mounts are used at the top? how do they connect to the frame,

Comment: Just a bracket at the top, screwed to the frame, and with enough space for a screw to slot through and slide up/down/left/right to secure (like a picture frame).

Comment: Thank you very much @MadsSkjern! I think the z-clip mentioned below is a great fit.

Comment: What kind of frame does the whiteboard have? You may be able to just drill holes through the frame, and mount it that way with cabinet screws.

Comment: Interesting idea! It's an aluminum frame, but it just feels like that's a lot of work, relative to just getting a bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rather than using a bracket, it seems like a better looking solution
   would be to predrill holes where you want these brackets in the
   whiteboard and fasten the board to the wall with bolts instead,
   similar to the method you used at the top.
2. If you feel that a bracket is the way to go, you could grab a few of
   those "L" steel angles that they sell at home depot (see the image
   below) and fasten to the underside of the whiteboard with the
   appropriate fastener for the whiteboard's frame material. You'd want
   to install about 4 of these.

[image]

3. Another bracket solution would be that Simpson Strong Tie also
   produces a Z-Clip shown in the image below. It would be able to
   resist the loads that the board would apply to it if you have
   already fastened at 2 points on the top. If you can cut back the
   tray and compromise on the 2" to say, 2 5/16", the Z2 would work
   well for this with wood filler between the bracket and the white
   board.

[image]

Comment: The issue with the "L" is the kids could still pull it away from the wall if they're not careful. I think the Z-clip is perfect, thank you!